# Zxing library possibility of inserting multiple values?

Tags: java, php, android, zxing

Is it possible to encode multiple values into QR code using zxing library. i have a textview with a survey question and an array of options. i want to encode this into a QR code but cant seem to find any relevant source?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it possible to encode multiple values into QR code using zxing library

Yes, just create a JSON with what ever data you need and convert it to string

and its easy to extract data from JSON when ever needed.

**Example:**

```
   {
  "question": "Is this useful",
  "options": [
    "yes",
    "no"
  ]
}
```